# Cannot query field "furniture" on type "RootMutation"

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-python

I am wanting to create a furniture object in graphiql by using following query where I get an error **Cannot query field "furniture" on type "RootMutation"**.

This is the query I did for creating a furniture object

```
mutation {
  newFurniture(input: {name: "graphFurniture", content: "This furniture is cool", category: "Bedroom Items"}) {
    clientMutationId
  }
    furniture{ // error is shown here 
            name
      content
      category {
        name
      }
    }
}
```

Here is my code for mutation

```
class FurnitureNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Furniture

class NewFurniture(graphene.ClientIDMutation):
    furniture = graphene.Field(FurnitureNode)
    class Input:
        name = graphene.String()
        content = graphene.String()
        category = graphene.String()
    @classmethod
    def mutate_and_get_payload(cls, input, context, info):
        furniture = Furniture(name=input.get('name'), content=input.get('content'),
        category=Category.objects.get(name=input.get('category')))
        furniture.save()
        return NewFurniture(furniture=furniture)

class NewFurnitureMutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    new_furniture = NewFurniture.Field()
```

Why am i getting such error?

Answer (score 0):

You can not query the furniture in a "mutation" scope. It is two separate actions:

```
mutation {
  newFurniture(input: {name: "graphFurniture", content: "This furniture is cool", category: "Bedroom Items"}) {
    clientMutationId
  }
}

query {
  furniture {
    name
    content
    category {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I get unname issue and when click on unnamed i get "This anonymous operation must be the only defined operation."